# JavaScript IF function to recognise mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently creating a website where I have a sticky fixed header. The website is built on Bootstrap, however since I don't really like a lot of the Bootstrap headers, I decided to make a simple one myself.

http://quarndoncurtaindesign.besaba.com/

The sticky headers works fine with some minor problems. However on mobile it is a different story. Since obviously the header takes up a lot of room vertically, it takes up too much space on a mobile device.

I decided it would be best to keep the menu in its sticky state however I am using this Javascript to add a "sticky" class on some elements so I can target it in CSS.

```
   $(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
    $('header h1').addClass("sticky");
    $('p#tagline').addClass("sticky");
    $('ul').addClass("sticky");
    $('a').addClass("sticky");
    $('#top').addClass("sticky");
  }
  else{
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
    $('header h1').removeClass("sticky");
    $('p#tagline').removeClass("sticky");
    $('ul').removeClass("sticky");
    $('a').removeClass("sticky");
    $('#top').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

Any advice pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting a mobile browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Comment: I suggest you to try media queries where you can change the header depending on the device screen size

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to use JS like this. By adding the class to the element you can then target the element using CSS.

There are a couple of issues with your approach however.

You only need to apply the 'sticky' class to the header. I don't see any reason why you would need to apply the sticky class to any other elements on the page.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
header.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
body {
    padding-top: 100px /* Height of header.*/
                       /*This will offset the content below the header */
}
```

Also, I don't think you even need to a JS if statement here as the header will always be sticky.

If you are having problems with the mobile view then you should use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to correct the offset of the content below the header

Answer (score 0):

You might get more value out of CSS media-queries than JS code in this case. They will allow you to recognise devices by - amongst other things - their screen size, and to specify different layouts for different setups.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first two answers that this is a use-case best suited for CSS and/or CSS media queries.

However, if you would still prefer to detect if the user is on a mobile device with JavaScript, you may be able to use the following (or a variation of the following) code:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

^ This code snippet was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/1525109